# Parse an InputStreamReader with DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, file, groovy, utf-8, document

I've very little Java experience. I'm trying to force a document to be read as UTF-8, but have come stuck trying to hook the InputStream reader to the document builder.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


if( pathToFile == null ) throw new Exception("You must supply a pathToFile parameter");

DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( pathToFile ), "utf-8" );

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( in ) );

Element records = builder.parse(reader).getDocumentElement();
```

Be grateful if someone can provide me with some pointers

Comment: Please elaborate "come stuck" in detail. What happens instead?

Comment: I get this: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStreamReader)

Comment: Look, there you have the answer already.

Comment: The `BufferedReader` is by the way not explicitly necessary. You can also just feed `in` to `parse()` method as `InputStreamReader` is a subclass of `Reader` already.

Comment: But then I get an error: No signature of method: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.InputStreamReader)

Comment: Oh right, it does not take an `Reader` at all, but just an `InputStream` or `InputSource`! See also the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html Just feed `FileInputStream` to it then or wrap the `Reader` in a `new InputSource()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Groovy, you can rid yourself of a lot of the Java cruft:

Not tried it, but:

```
if( pathToFile == null ) throw new Exception("You must supply a pathToFile parameter");

Element records = new File( pathToFile ).withReader( "utf-8" ) { r ->
  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().with { b ->
    b.parse( new InputSource( r ) ).documentElement
  }
}
```

should work...

Comment: It is Groovy, but your example gives me an error: unable to resolve class InputSource, is there something extra I should import?

Comment: Yes, [org.xml.sax.InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html). I don't believe DocumentBuilder can call parse on a Reader

Answer (score 9):

Don't wrap an `InputStreamReader` around your `InputStreamReader`. (**EDIT** Also, since there's no method to parse XML from a Reader, you need to wrap the reader in an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html)):

```
if( pathToFile == null )
    throw new Exception("You must supply a pathToFile parameter");

DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder();

InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream( pathToFile ), "utf-8" );

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( in ); // CHANGED

InputSource input = new InputSource(reader);

Element records = builder.parse(input).getDocumentElement();
```

Comment: I get the same error as mentioned in the comments above: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedReader) -- I'm certain I must have missed something, but what?

Comment: Thanks Ted. Although I have found your example much easier to follow, I accepted the other answer because it is slightly more condense and there is a lot I can learn from it.

Comment: Hi, When using the Ted's solution : input.getEncoding() returns null. And the inputStream is always a non UTF-8 stream :(